# How to get options element by id and output text

Tags: javascript

Could someone help me with this little javascript.  I want the rersult to show in NA only when option value 2 is selected. I want 11" to show will show. Need a simple script to output custom text based on value text. I do know  i have value="2" listed twice. I cannot use the value field.

```
<select id="sizing-change" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="2">12"</option>
    <option value="2" id="test">11"</option>
</select>

<div class="sizefinal">
    Suggested Size: <span id="finalsize">NA</span>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {         
    if(document.getElementById("test").value == "11") {
    document.getElementById("finalsize").innerHTML = "Size: 11";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the text of the option like

```js
function myFunction() {
  var el = document.getElementById("sizing-change");
  if (el.options[el.selectedIndex].text.trim() == '11"') {
    document.getElementById("finalsize").innerHTML = "Size: 11";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("finalsize").innerHTML = "NA";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="sizing-change" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="2">12"</option>
  <option value="2" id="test">11"</option>
</select>

<div class="sizefinal">
  Suggested Size: <span id="finalsize">NA</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can alter the `value` field of option to different values(which you should) then you can try this:

```
<select id="sizing-change" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="11" id="test">11</option>
</select>
<div class="sizefinal">Suggested Size: <span id="finalsize">NA</span>

</div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        if (document.getElementById("sizing-change").value == 11) {
            document.getElementById("finalsize").innerHTML = "Size: 11";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/784/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var finalsize = document.querySelector('#finalsize');
var sizingChange = document.querySelector('#sizing-change')
var testOption = sizingChange.querySelector('#test');

myFunction(sizingChange);

function myFunction(element) {
  var checked = element.querySelector(':checked');
  
   if (checked == testOption) {
       finalsize.innerHTML = "Size: " + element.querySelector(':checked').text;
   } else {
       finalsize.innerHTML = 'NA';
   }
}
```

```html
<select id="sizing-change" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option value="2">12"</option>
    <option value="2" id="test">11"</option>
</select>

<div class="sizefinal">
    Suggested Size: <span id="finalsize">NA</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't great, you should explain the issues in the OP's code and why your answer fixes them. This code is quite contorted, the initial call to *myFunction* should be qualified to use the load event or be after the elements in question. *element.value* should never equal `11` since both options have a value and neither is `11`, so you changed the value even though the OP said "I can't use the value".

Comment: What i really needed it to do was spit out the word test when 11 is selected. I cannot change 11" either. I cleary wasn't thinking last night before i hit the sack. This answer only fixes half a problem.

Comment: fixed: specified conditions